# Facebook Application Related Inquiry

Tags: php, jquery

I want to ask a question that if i make my website users to log in through facebook and i create an application in facebook developer zone, it will be chargeable or free of cost ? ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook login feature and application creation is free of cost.